# Precalculus Discrete Math Venn Diagram

Tags: probability

Among a group of 72 investors, 21 owned shares of Stock A, 34 owned shares of Stock B, 41 owned shares of Stock C, 12 owned shares of both Stock A and Stock B, 13 owned shares of Stock A and Stock C, 19 Owned shares of Stock B and Stock C, and 9 owned shares of all three. How many investors did not have shares in any of the three? How many owned shares of either Stock A or Stock C but not Stock B?
A) 11; 27 
B) 20; 23
C) 11; 32
D) 11; 23

I have already tried creating my own venn-diagram, and tried to sort out these numbers but have failed to sort them correctly, either ending up with too many total investors than the question allows- or falling short of any other the answer choices presented. I'm now stuck on how to proceed because I do not understand how to correctly divide the numbers in the venn diagram and completing the diagram correctly. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Subtract 9 from the A, B, and A +B part?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you drew the diagram correctly. If you did, then the circle for Stock A is labelled 21; the intersection between Stock A and Stock B is 12; the label between A & C is 13; and the label for all 3 stocks is 9. These values are all stated in the question.

Now we have to determine the true values for each section. For example, the problem states that 21 people owned Stock A, but this includes everyone who also one one or both of the other stocks. The problem states that 9 people owned all 3 stocks and that 12 people owned both Stock A and Stock B. These are not separate sets; the 9 that own all 3 are a subset of the 12 that own A & B. With subtraction, we can determine the actual number of investors that own A & B *only*.

Similarly, we can determine how many own *only* A & C by subtracting those that own all 3. And once we know the true numbers for the intersections with A, we can determine the number of investors that own Stock A *only*.

Is this enough to proceed? You will have to determine the true amounts for 7 categories, but with logic and subtraction, you can arrive at the correct answers.